# How to set an event on column of TableView

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I'm building an app with appcelerator studio.

I have a TableView with some TableViewRow. So I have the last column that have an ImageView (delete.png), then I want that when the user click on this image, this row it is to delete.

So I have this code for the table:

```
<Alloy>
    <View class="containerClinicalFolder" >
        <TableView id="table" class="table" onClick="doClick">
            <TableViewSection id="table" >

            </TableViewSection>
        </TableView>

        <Button id="button" class="buttonLanguage" onClick="changeLanguage"
            visible="false" traduzione="true"></Button> 

    </View>
</Alloy>
```

and this is the event:

```
function doClick(e){
    if(e.source.apiName == "Ti.UI.ImageView"){
        $.tableContact.deleteRow(e.index);  
    }
}
```

but not works

Comment: 1. remove the onclick from the table. 2. in your controller you are adding rows to the tableview. in the createtableviewrow you add a refrence to the row (eg the id of the record) 4. after adding rows you add an Addeventlistener  to the tableview

Answer (score 0):

I believe that line 3:

```
<TableView id="table" class="table" onClick="doClick">
```

Should be

```
<TableView id="table" class="table" onClick="doClick()">
```

Comment: no no the method doClick is called, but not works correctly. 
I have in my table 4 column, the 4° column have the delete image, I want the if the user click on the 4° column the doClick method must delete that row